# How do you write the same bytes twice in C?

Tags: c

```
short i = 1;
fwrite(&i, sizeof(i), 1, file);
fwrite(&i, sizeof(i), 1, file);
```

Is that proper? I want to write the same `i` twice.

Comment: yes, this is write way to that.

Comment: Have you tried it? What makes you think it would not work?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg because this is my first program in C

Comment: The `fwrite` function doesn't modify the data you provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it; just remember to check the return value.

Comment: Why should I check the return value?

Comment: To detect whether writing to the file succeeded. If it didn't, appropriate error handling is required.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work fine. Alternatively you could declare an array of two and use a single `fwrite`, which would theoretically be more efficient:

```
short i[2] = {1, 1};
fwrite(i, sizeof(short), 2, file);
```